# Firebase authwithpassword() authenticating all credentials in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I'm particularly new to firebase, angularJS, ionic and coding in general, so this question might have an easy solution.

This is my controller for Firebase auth in Ionic:

```
    .controller('authCtrl', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.data = {};

$scope.signupEmail = function(){
  var ref = new Firebase("https://places-of-interest.firebaseio.com");

  ref.createUser({
  email    : $scope.data.email,
  password : $scope.data.password
}, function(error, userData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
    $state.go('start')
  }
});

};

$scope.loginEmail = function(){
  var ref = new Firebase("https://places-of-interest.firebaseio.com");

  ref.authWithPassword({
  "email": scope.data.email,
  "password": $scope.data.password
}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
    $state.go('dash')
  }
});
```

With this code I am able to add a new user to the database and the entries are also visible, but when I login, the console output simply logs me in no matter what input I give for the login credentials.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: need to see more code. I have a working example here using the new Firebase - https://github.com/aaronksaunders/golftalk-sample/

Answer (score 0):

try changing your `ref` var to:

```
var ref = new $firebaseAuth("https://places-of-interest.firebaseio.com");
```

Remember to call the directive on your controller, like this:

```
.controller('authCtrl', function($scope, $state, $firebaseAuth) {
    ...
}
```

And if you don't have it, add [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire) in your index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```